# How do I get multiple groups for a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

This code:

```
string1 = "I will drill for a well in walla walla washington."
/(w.ll) /.match(string1)
```

is returning only `will`.

Shouldn't it be returning `will` and `well` also?

Check: http://rubular.com/r/48K8o5mzUX

How do I get multiple groups for a regex in Ruby?

Comment: Perl, and other languages, support the `g` flag which tells their Regular Expression parser to look through the target string for all matches. Ruby doesn't have `g`, so we use `scan` as @lucapette recommends.

Comment: `String#match` is usually used in boolean context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's working fine and it's the expected behaviour. Probably you want to use [scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan), like in the following:

```
1.9.2 (main):0 > string1.scan(/(w.ll)/)
=> [["will"], ["well"], ["wall"], ["wall"]]
```

Comment: Why not add some example output so the OP sees why it is the right answer?

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood String#match I think